# ERC20 token. Cannot get variable nor use methods with deployed contract

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask

I have deployed a ERC20 token contract via Metamask on the Ropsten network. The issue is that I am trying to interact with it via web3. I have followed the answers provided in SO and SE, related to token transfer and method calling.

As you will see, I am not transferring tokens here, but I am using my solidity contract method to set the initial owners of the token. The method in the contract receives 2 arguments, an address and also a tokenId.

When I use the code to transfer a token to the test Metamask account, it fails, in the sense that, if I enter into this test account and import the token, it has none.

For reference, This tokenId, is basically provided by my variable nextTokenIdToAssign, which I call this way:

```
const tokenIdToAssign = contract.nextTokenIdToAssign.call(function(err, res){
    if(!err) { tokenIdToAssign = res; }
    else { console.log("Error"); }
  });
```

Oddly, when I try to console.log, it returns as undefined. Also, following the question comments, of [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/what-is-the-correct-way-to-access-public-variable-from-contract-in-truffle-then?noredirect=1&lq=1) I used

```
const test = web3.eth.getCode(contractAddress);
```

It just returns a null. The comments suggest that there is crash in my constructor, or a parent constructor.

Is there some important detail that I am missing here?

The complete code is the following:

```
const config = require('../config');
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();
const infuraApi = (config.infura.infuraApiKey);

//Set a provider (HttpProvider)
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/'+infuraApi));
}

const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var accountAddressHex = (config.metamaskAccount.metamaskAddressHex);
var accountAddressPrivateKey  = (config.metamaskAccount.metamaskAddressPrivateKey);
var privateKey = new Buffer(accountAddressPrivateKey, 'hex');

var count = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accountAddressHex);
var contractAddress = (config.solidityContract.contractAddress);
var contractAbiArray = (config.solidityContract.contractABI);
var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbiArray).at(contractAddress);

const testSendAccount= "0x...";

const gasPrice = web3.eth.gasPrice;
const gasPriceHex = web3.toHex(gasPrice);
const gasLimitHex = web3.toHex(30000000);
//const tokenTransferAmount = 1;
var tokenIdToAssignHex = contract.nextTokenIdToAssign.sendTransaction( {from: accountAddressHex}, function(err, hash){
        if(!err) { tokenIdToAssignHex = hash;
        console.log(tokenIdToAssignHex); }
        else { console.log("Error"); }
      });


var tokenIdToAssign = contract.nextTokenIdToAssign.call(function(err, res){
        if(!err) { tokenIdToAssign = res; }
        else { console.log("Error"); }
      });
    const test = web3.eth.getCode(contractAddress);

var rawTransaction = {
          "from": accountAddressHex,
          "nonce": web3.toHex(count),
          "gasPrice": gasPriceHex,
          "gasLimit": gasLimitHex,
          "to": contractAddress,
          "value": "0x0",
          "data": contract.setInitialOwner.getData(testSendAccount, tokenIdToAssign, {from: accountAddressHex}), //contract.transfer.getData("0xCb...", 10, {from: "0x26..."}),
          "chainId": 0x03 //Ropsten id is 3, replace with 1 for main
      };

      var tx = new EthereumTx(rawTransaction);
      tx.sign(privateKey);
      var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

      web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
          if (!err) { console.log( 'contract creation tx: ' + hash); }
          else {
              console.log(err);
              return;
            }
      });
```

**EDIT 1**

Here is the contract code for the setInitialOwner:

```
function setInitialOwner(address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public
    onlyOwner
    tokensRemainingToAssign
    tenKLimit (_tokenId)
    yesZeroAddressOwner (_tokenId) 
    notSelfSend (_to, _tokenId) {

        tokenIdToOwner[_tokenId] = _to;
        balanceOfAddress[_to] = balanceOfAddress[_to].add(1);
        emit Assign(_to, _tokenId);

        tokenIndexArray.push(_tokenId);

        uint256 length = balanceOf(msg.sender);
        ownedTokensIndexMapping[_tokenId] = length;
        addressToTokenIdByIndex[msg.sender][length] = _tokenId;

        nextTokenIdToAssign = nextTokenFunc(nextTokenIdToAssign);
       hypeKillsTokensRemainingToAssign = tokensRemainingToAssign.sub(1);
        }
```

**EDIT 2**
I have changed the tokenToAssign and added the

```
var tokenIdToAssignHex = contract.nextTokenIdToAssign.sendTransaction( {from: accountAddressHex}, function(err, hash){
    if(!err) { tokenIdToAssignHex = hash;
    console.log(tokenIdToAssignHex); }
    else { console.log("Error"); }
  });
```

Comment: Is `nextTokenIdToAssign` a `constant` function? It may help to post your contract code as well.

Comment: I have added, the contract code for the setInitialOwner method and the nextTokenFunc function. Basically I set, my next token id in the constructor at 1. The rest of the token ids that get assigned are determined by the function.

Comment: Ok...`nextTokenIdToAssign` is a public state variable, so you're fine there. Did you `console.log` it's value inside the callback? You're providing a callback to `call` and setting the variable there, but also are attempting to assign it as the return value. Stick to one approach (Preferably, the callback. Then put everything from `rawTransaction` down inside the callback.).

Comment: I was able to make one transaction. But I cannot manage to update the nextTokenToAssign with the tokenIdToAssignHexin order to updata the next token id. So I end up with token 1, which will revert any further transaction. I have added the tokenIdToAssignHex, but it yields an error.

Comment: So, in order to update my `nextTokenIdToAssign` I had to send a `rawTransaction` again to `nextTokenIdToAssign` , since infura does not support `sendTransaction`. The problem at this point it is still not updating. Could it be caused be the setter function `nextTokenFunc(uint256 _tokenId)`, taking into account that `nextTokenIdToAssign` is essentially changed during `setInitialOwner` with an internal function like `nextTokenIdToAssign`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that my `nextTokenToAssign` variable was not updating properly.

I used [myetherwallet.com](https://myetherwallet.com) to deploy the contract and to check its value. When I deployed the contract, if afterwards I did not call the constructor function, setting the initial value of `nextTokenToAssign` to 1, it would not update during the successive call to the `setInitialOwner` function. So the solution simply was to simply call the function.